# Fix/replacement for v-brake part

Tags: brakes, rim-brake

I finally found out the answer as to why my [v brake is not returning to open position](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43157/v-brake-arm-not-returning-to-open-position).

[image]
[image]

If you look closely, the screw that is supposed to hold spring is not doing its job; the spring slips down when I try to apply tension. I'm not sure what that black plastic thing is called but I'm guessing that it must have a groove there in order for the spring to slide down under the screw.

Are there replacement parts for that or can that still be fixed? Or do I need to replace the whole v-brake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it's called anything, which it usually isn't, it would be something like a "spring carrier." What's going on here is fairly common to see on brakes like this. Mostly it happens when, as in the picture, the spring tension adjustment screw is threaded all the way in. Taking it out some, and then adjusting the other one on the other arm to compensate, may allow it to make contact with the spring nub rather than what it's doing now. If that doesn't work, i.e. if it's doing this no matter how screwed in it is, then taking the whole thing apart and bending the spring ever so slightly may work.

Replacement parts aren't available, although a much better complete brake is about $10US.

Comment: Yeah, it still slides no matter how far the screw is threaded in. I'll try to bend the spring nub and update when I get to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, still slipping. I guess I need to replace the whole thing. Thanks!